# How to filter an observable passed into an angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm new to `RxJs` `operators and Observables` in general and was not sure how to get this simple code to work.

I have created a component called '`family-list`' that is bound to an observable of '`PlanMember[]`'. This is passed in from a container component.

Inside of this component, I want to be able to filter out the plan members so that we leave out the member with `userType` '`Owner`'. The code i have now fails because '`planMembers`' is undefined.

Please help!

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pv-family-list',
  templateUrl: './family-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./family-list.component.scss']
})
export class FamilyListComponent{
  @Input() planMembers: Observable<PlanMember[]>;
  @Output() remove: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'email', 'status', 'cycleEnd', 'actions'];

  constructor() { 
    this.planMembers.pipe(map( (members) =>  members.filter(m => m.userId !== 'Owner') )).subscribe();
  }
  removeUser (userId : string) {
    this.remove.emit(userId);
  }
}
```

EDIT:
After using ngOnit to filter -- 
My page will load the component, but still getting errors. I'm also not even getting the member-list to filter properly -- still have all the members

So I have a "Subscription.container" component that holds this family-list component. I retrieve the list of family members from the store. `this.familyPlanMembers$ = store.select(fromAccount.getPlanMembers);` Then, i bind my family-list planMembers with an Async Pipe: `<pv-family-list (remove)="cancelMemberSubscription($event)" [planMembers]="(familyPlanMembers$ | async)" > </pv-family-list>` While the family-list loads, I'm getting this: TypeError: "this.planMembers is null"

Component Now:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pv-family-list',
  templateUrl: './family-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./family-list.component.scss']
})
export class FamilyListComponent implements OnChanges{
  @Input() planMembers: PlanMember[];
  @Output() remove: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'email', 'status', 'cycleEnd', 'actions'];

  ngOnChanges() { 
    this.planMembers = this.planMembers.filter(m => m.userType !== 'Owner');
  }

  removeUser (userId : string) {
    this.remove.emit(userId);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `constructor` time, your `@Input` is not defined yet.

Move your code in `ngOnInit`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pv-family-list',
  templateUrl: './family-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./family-list.component.scss']
})
export class FamilyListComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() planMembers: Observable<PlanMember[]>;
  @Output() remove: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'email', 'status', 'cycleEnd', 'actions'];

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.planMembers.pipe(map( (members) =>  members.filter(m => m.userId !== 'Owner') )).subscribe();
  }
  removeUser (userId : string) {
    this.remove.emit(userId);
  }
}
```

Then it also depends how do you pass this input through this component, and how do you fetch the data, otherwise you should implement `ngOnChanges` rather than `ngOnInit`, or use a `set` on the `@Input` or a lot of other approaches are also possible

Comment: Thanks for the response. My page seems less broken now, but still getting errors.
So I have a "Subscription.container" component that holds this family-list component.

I retrieve the list of family members from the store.
```   
 this.familyPlanMembers$ = store.select(fromAccount.getPlanMembers);
```

Then, i bind my family-list planMembers with an Async Pipe:
```
<pv-family-list (remove)="cancelMemberSubscription($event)" [planMembers]="(familyPlanMembers$ | async)" > </pv-family-list>
```
While the family-list loads, I'm getting this:
TypeError: "this.planMembers is null"

Comment: when do you fetch them from the store? and what do you mean by "less bron but still errors"? which errors? you can even pass directly the array of `PlanMember` if this is your case

Comment: thanks, I updated my original question with how some more code. I'm grabbing the data from a store, which is loaded in via Http request during a "Load" action + effect. Not sure why 'this.planMembers' is null inside of ngOnit though

Comment: Because the data is ready after that the child is init. Just to see if this is the case, try to use ngOnChanges instead of ngOnInit

Comment: ngOnChanges seems to at least get my component to filter the list properly. I ended up giving up on doing the filtering from the UI for now. I think my problems might have to do with not reading the Angular Materials Table API too thoroughly. I just made the server request no longer return the owner user since it's a lot easier for me to implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined because it is not initialized. 
You should do filtering in ngOnInit and ngOnChanges hook or use set method

```
_planMembers:  Observable<PlanMember[]>;

@Input
set planMembers(planMembers: Observable<PlanMember[]]) {
    this._planMembers = planMembers;
    this._planMembers
        .pipe(map( (members) =>  members.filter(m => m.userId !== 'Owner') 
    )).subscribe();

}
```

This will be invoked every time when planMembers input would change.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers already mentioned, the Observable isn't yet defined in the constructor. A constructor should only be used for DI or assignments imho.

I would suggest **not** to pass the observable as an input to your child components but to pass it as "just" an array. This will make your application faster, easier to work with and easier to test. To pass it as an array, use the `async` pipe.

```
<pv-family-list [planMembers]="planMembers$ | async"><pv-family-list/>
```

Comment: why do you say "This will make your application faster"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using the async pipe, and now I'm just passing in "PlanMember[]" to my family-list component. Inside this, I am doing 

ngOnInit() { 
    this.planMembers.filter(m => m.userType !== 'Owner');
  }
--- 
error that this.planMembers is null though.

Comment: @timdeschryver, thanks for the link. It is a long video :) back to the original question, why does `| async` make it more performant? under the hood, both will listen to observable event changes? Any other reasons?